# Code refactoring with existing classes in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I code in C++ and since the interface keyword is  not there in the language, I will  use  interface as a concept( a contract) here.

Suppose you have an interface  say IBase, which has been implemented by dozens of classes. Now you need to add another method in that interface IBase.

What would be the approach to make that change in minimal way to solve the problem of overriding that method in all implementing classes?

One way could be adding  the new method with a default implementation in the Ibase class and have the derived class that need it override it.

In the above solution I feel like I am going wrong at two places, breaking the open closed principle by touching the interface and also breaking the contract by telling the user you can also call another method.

Another thing that strikes me here is , I am adding a method to the base and only one derived class is overriding it , which basically means that the other classes don’t need that method.

So that brings me to the another  solution, where the class which needs this method would inherit from another class which provides this feature or  use composition to use the feature of another class.

With the above solution I hit another problem, how would the client access the new functionality of the derived class through the Ibase interface. Dynamic dispatch in C++ would only work if the function is present in the base class.

Can someone please help!

**UPDATE**

I just coded up my understanding based on the comments below, but now the client code looks messy, it have to know which interface to use for extra functionality. Should we abstract the code below using factory/ abstract factory ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class IBase {
    public:
     virtual void test() = 0; 
};

class INewInterface {
    public:
     virtual void newMethod() = 0; 
};

class Derived : public IBase {
    public:
    virtual void test () {
        cout<< " Derived  " << endl;
    }
};

class DerivedSecond: public IBase, public INewInterface {
    public:
    virtual void test() {
        cout<< " Derived Second " << endl;
    }

    void newMethod( ) {
        cout<< " newMethod " << endl;
    }
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

    // Client code
    //Client needs to cast to two different interfaces to get access to the new functionality.
    // Probably should use a factory here 
    INewInterface * pNewInterfacePtr = dynamic_cast< INewInterface * > ( new DerivedSecond );
    IBase *         pIbasePtr        = dynamic_cast< IBase * > ( new DerivedSecond );

    pIbasePtr->test();
    pNewInterfacePtr->newMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply creating another interface and use that only with the classes that are supposed to implement it. Changing the existing interface breaks the contract, and must be implemented in all classes that use it.

Comment: Hello, πάντα ῥεῖ in my question above that is the second solution I thought of going the way you have proposed in the answer. However, I am not sure how I would access the new functionality through the IBase interface. Or is it not possible at all? What should be my approach to handle such scenarios? or is my design flawed and I should have done it differently?

Comment: You cannot directly access the new functionality through `IBase` directly, but you can use a `dynamic_cast` to probe for the new interface.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ why not injecting two interfaces to client class?

Comment: @PiotrNycz That might have big impacts on the overall client API design.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ maybe inject this new interface to client constructor?

Comment: I agree with you, dynamic_cast <concrete*> and if it succeeds, call concrete_pointer->newMethod, but doesn't this defeat the entire purpose of using the interface and having vitrual functions, to access the extra functionality the client will have to do dynamic_cast in their code and also switch on the types. Isn't there a better way to handle this ?

Comment: @deb No I meant `dynamic_cast<INewInterface*>`. You must have misunderstood something from my very 1st comment.

Comment: It sound to me like the caller needs to know the type of the implementation. Then this method should not be part of the *base interface* because the caller already needs to take special action to know that the call is relevant.

Comment: What triggered the need for this special function that is only relevant to *some* of the implementing classes? The place in the software that this need arises is likely the place where the software knows the specific typeof the object and (ideally) it can access it through a correctly types reference.

Comment: @Galik the need arose from the fact that I am working on an already existing class hierarchy and I have to add a new role to one of the derived classes without disturbing the existing code.

Comment: But when does that *new role* come into play? Whatever logic requires that *new role* to to exist *for specific types* should also have all the type information to avoid using the more general *base interface*. Without knowing more specifics I think t is difficult envisage the best solution. But a *new role* that other *sibling types* do not share suggests a *new interface*. And perhaps a new *container* holding pointers to only those objects that implement this *new role*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to really know what will suit your situation because you evidently have a working system which may or may not benefit from anything we might suggest.

However I have produced an example of how you *can* manage multiple subtypes with separate and/or overlapping responsibilities. This approach is to have a *master* container holding ownership of **all** the objects using a `std::unique_ptr` to ensure they all get deleted and we have no memory leaks.

In *addition* to that *master* container we have separate containers for different *views*. Each *view* holds references (raw pointers) to those elements with a specific responsibility not shared with other types.

Perhaps it may be of some use in your situation, perhaps not:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Role
{
public:
    virtual ~Role() {}
};

class RoleOne
: public virtual Role
{
public:
    virtual void do_role_one_stuff() = 0;
};

class RoleTwo
: public virtual Role
{
public:
    virtual void do_role_two_stuff() = 0;
};

class ItemA
: public RoleOne
{
public:
    void do_role_one_stuff() override { std::cout << "Item A in Role One\n"; }
};

class ItemB
: public RoleOne
, public RoleTwo
{
public:
    void do_role_one_stuff() override { std::cout << "Item B in Role One\n"; }
    void do_role_two_stuff() override { std::cout << "Item B in Role Two\n"; }
};

class ItemC
: public RoleTwo
{
public:
    void do_role_two_stuff() override { std::cout << "Item C in Role Two\n"; }
};

class Resources
{
    // unique_ptr ensures deletion (no memory leaks)
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Role>> all; // owning container

    // raw 'access' pointers share access (no need to share ownership)
    std::vector<RoleOne*> ones; // alternate 'view' (no ownership)
    std::vector<RoleTwo*> twos; // alternate 'view' (no ownership)

public:
    void add_item(Role* item)
    {
        // manage ALL items life-spans here
        all.emplace_back(item);

        // add one-centric items to the one-centric view
        if(auto one = dynamic_cast<RoleOne*>(item))
            ones.emplace_back(one);

        // add two-centric items to the two-centric view
        if(auto two = dynamic_cast<RoleTwo*>(item))
            twos.emplace_back(two);
    }

    void do_business()
    {
        // ItemA and ItemB types do this kind of business
        std::cout << "\nDoing role one business:\n";
        for(auto role: ones)
            role->do_role_one_stuff();

        // ItemB and ItemC types do this kind of business
        std::cout << "\nDoing role two business:\n";
        for(auto role: twos)
            role->do_role_two_stuff();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Resources res;

    res.add_item(new ItemA);
    res.add_item(new ItemB);
    res.add_item(new ItemC);
    res.add_item(new ItemB);
    res.add_item(new ItemA);
    res.add_item(new ItemC);

    res.do_business();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Doing role one business:
Item A in Role One
Item B in Role One
Item B in Role One
Item A in Role One

Doing role two business:
Item B in Role Two
Item C in Role Two
Item B in Role Two
Item C in Role Two
```

Comment: I do not undertand your answer. It is quite cool code (I do not discuss it) and It seems similar to Command Pattern. However, @deb is asking how you can extend an interface without break it.

Comment: @blashser In the comments section it became clear that deb only wanted to use the 'extended' interface for *some* of the subtypes but not all. My solution was to create a *new interface* to represent those subtypes that had a new role and to create a separate *view* of the data that contains only those subtypes that implement this new role.

Comment: It is true @Galik . However, this means a complete new design. You need to rewrite all the existing code (Somtimes, and refactoring is one of them, is the best option and with a good battery of unit tests  you do not have to worry a lot) but a less invasive solution would be a new interface that it has a has-a relationship with the other one. This is what I suggest in my answer.

Comment: @blashser I don't think my approach necessarily requires a redesign. All you need to do is create a new *interface* for those *types* that need to take on the new role. They need to inherit that new *interface* and provide their own implementation. Then, all is needed is to *conditionally* add them to their *specific view* when you add them to the system. My example here presents how you might design that into the system as an original feature. But you can apply the concepts presented in this example without necessarily redesigning what you have.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking that the previous code was adapted to this new interface. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, principles are not rules. You will find sometimes that you have to break some principle in the real worl and it will be a good decision if you understand what you are doing. Then, the option of creating a new dummy method in IBase could be your solution.

If you do not want to break the actual interface, I would use composition and delegation. But I do not know your issue. Maybe my solution does not fit in your case.

```
class IBase {
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
};
class INewIfc {
protected:
    IBase* ifc;
public:
    INewIfc(IBase* _ifc) : ifc(_ifc) {}
    ~INewIfc() {}
    virtual void newMethod() = 0;
    IBase* getIfc() {return ifc;}
}
```

Then you create your concrete classes from IBase (what you had) or use composition of IBase and the new interface to create new ones without affecting the previous classes.